# Linq variable declare conditional statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a LINQ query that will have two different results from the variable "filter". How to I declare the query variable "sales" outside the conditional statement?

```
        Int filter = sale.filter;

        if (filter is null)
        {
            var sales = from s in _db.Sales
                select s;
        }
        else
        {
           var  sales = from s in _db.Sales
                where s.SalesStatusID == salesStatusfilter
                select s;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it as a `List<Sale>` (I'm supposing `Sales` is a collection of `Sale`'s.

```
    Int filter = sale.filter;

    List<Sale> sales;

    if (filter == null) {
        sales = _db.Sales.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        sales = _sb.Sales
                .Where(s => s.SalesStatusID == salesStatusfilter)
                .ToList();
    }
```

Depending on what you want to do with the data it should suffice.

Comment: Great @AlexD! I found another solution, more elegant:
    `var sales = _db.Sales.Where(s => filter == null ? true : s.SalesStatusID == salesStatusfilter);`

Answer (score 1):

Declare it as `IQueryable<Sale>` if using EF or `IEnumerable<Sale>` if using LINQ to Objects.

If you hover over `sales`, Visual Studio can tell you what to use.

Comment: yeah I tried that and it just throws an error without any info at all.

Comment: @AlexD What is the error? We can't help if you if you don't tell us what the problem is. :) You should edit your answer to include the error.

Comment: That is just the thing. Visual Studio says there is a build error. Doesn't say anything at all about what the error is. Heck the page even loads without any data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Where` based on the condition, which give you possibility to using `var` without declaring type explicitly.

```
var sales = _db.Sales;
if (filter != null)
{
    sales = sales.Where(s => s.SalesStatusID == salesStatusfilter);
}

// use result later
foreach (var sale in sales)
{
    // ...
}
```